# Constraint check on multiple tables while inserting record

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, alter

I have the database scheme like this..

```
create table Photographer(
id int primary key references Person(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
livesIn int not null references Location(id) on update cascade on delete no action
);
create table Specialty(
photographer int references Photographer(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
type enum('portrait','landscape','sport'),
primary key(photographer, type)
);
create table Photo(
id int primary key,
takenAt timestamp not null,
takenBy int references Photographer(id) on update cascade on delete no action,
photographedAt int references Location(id) on update cascade on delete no action,
type enum('portrait','landscape','sport')
);
```

I have to constrain the database so that a photographer is qualified to take a photo having type t if the photographer has t as one of the photographer's specialties.

My attempts were not working.

```
/*Attempt 1*/
ALTER TABLE Photo ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_1      
CHECK (Photo.type in (SELECT Specialty.type FROM Specialty,Photo,Photographer 
WHERE Photo.takenBy = Photographer.id 
AND Photographer.id = Specialty.photographer 
AND Specialty.type = Photo.type));
/*Attempt 2 using exists instead of 'in'*/
ALTER TABLE Photo ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_1      
CHECK (exists (SELECT * FROM Specialty,Photo,Photographer 
WHERE Photo.takenBy = Photographer.id 
AND Photographer.id = Specialty.photographer 
AND Specialty.type = Photo.type));
```

Is there anything particular that I am doing it wrong here ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you already created type as enum. Setting the field attribute also as nullable, you can achive that the field must have a value and the value can be one of _enum('portrait','landscape','sport')_

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See [Section 13.1.17, “`CREATE TABLE` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html). The reason for accepting but ignoring syntax clauses is for compatibility, to make it easier to port code from other SQL servers, and to run applications that create tables with references. See [Section 1.8.5, “MySQL Differences from Standard SQL”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/differences-from-ansi.html).

You have a couple of options:

1. Use [`FOREIGN KEY` constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), which require that all tables use the `InnoDB` storage engine:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Specialty
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (photographer) REFERENCES Photographer (id);

   ALTER TABLE Photo
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (takenBy, type) REFERENCES Specialty (photographer, type);
   ```
2. Use triggers:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER foo1 BEFORE INSERT ON Photo FOR EACH ROW
   IF NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM   Specialty s JOIN Photographer p ON s.photographer = p.id
     WHERE  p.id = NEW.takenBy AND s.type = NEW.type
   ) THEN CALL raise.error;

   CREATE TRIGGER foo2 BEFORE UPDATE ON Photo FOR EACH ROW
   IF NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM   Specialty s JOIN Photographer p ON s.photographer = p.id
     WHERE  p.id = NEW.takenBy AND s.type = NEW.type
   ) THEN CALL raise.error;
   ```